# Removing long tab-like white space in between strings in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this

```
StackOverflow rocks; Google; Facebook; Yahoo; Bing;            WhatsApp
```

I would like to trim the long white space before `WhatsApp`, so as to have:

```
StackOverflow rocks; Google; Facebook; Yahoo; Bing; WhatsApp
```

With just one whitespace.

I tried this in Perl:

```
my $keywords = "StackOverflow rocks; Google; Facebook; Yahoo; Bing;            WhatsApp";

$keywords =~ s/\s+//g;

print($keywords);
```

and I get:

```
StackOverflowrocks;Google;Facebook;Yahoo;Bing;WhatsApp
```

Which is not the desired output. Any way to fix this?

Comment: `$keywords =~ s/\s+/ /g;`

Comment: Thanks, that works.@WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's look at your code:

```
$keywords =~ s/\s+//g;
```

What does this do? It looks for one or more spaces (`\s+`) and replaces them with an empty string. And that's what you see in your results. You are basically removing all of the spaces. And that's not what you want.

But you were close. You don't want to replace the spaces with an empty string, you want to replace them with a space. So that would be like this:

```
$keywords =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

That works, but it's probably a little inefficient. Because you're looking for all sequences of one or more spaces, you're replacing all of the single spaces (which are already correct) with a space. Which is more work than you really need to to.

Better, perhaps, to look for all sequences of two or more spaces and replace that with a space.

```
$keywords =~ s/\s\s+/ /g;
```